# Is it OK if a letter of recommendation misstates the name of my degree?

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

I am applying for a graduate degree program.

In a letter of recommendation, my professor misstated my *MS in Telecommunication Networks* as an *MS in Telecommunication*.

Can this be an issue?

Comment: It is unclear whether you mean the degree you are *applying to* is MS in telecommunication networks, or if this is the degree you already have. Regardless, you should choose a more descriptive title -- I have made a suggested edit with one possibility.

Answer (score 6):

No.  The committee will want to know what your reference can tell them about you, not so much whether they can pass a pop quiz on the exact name of the program you're trying to get into.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly this sort of thing doesn't matter. I just finished reading some recommendation letters. Some of them were addressed to the wrong university. This is a much more obvious mistake, but I know this happens just because reference writers are busy. I certainly didn't go through and check all of the details at the level you mention. The only time this would stand out is if the applicant made a big deal out of one point, and the referee contradicted them.